# Check code quality on CI server using Husky and/or Lint-Staged

Tags: git, pre-commit, husky, lint-staged

In the Python world, it's common to use [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com/), which provides a `git commit` hook, and then on your CI server you can run `pre-commit run --all-files` which will ignore the commit and run the linting tools on all files. This ensures that, for example, pull requests must pass the linting requirements or the build will fail.

However, in the JS world, it seems common to use [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) + [Lint-Staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged), which satisfies the `git commit` hook requirement, but doesn't seem to have an equivalent to `pre-commit run --all-files`. How do Husky users check pull request code in their CI?

Comment: note that `pre-commit` (though it's implemented in python) is not a python-specific tool -- working for any programming language

Comment: Have you tried using Learna.JS setup?

Answer (score -1):

for a CI equivalent you can use something like [`file-changes-action`](https://github.com/dorner/file-changes-action)

[related post](https://dev.to/flipp-engineering/linting-only-changed-files-with-github-actions-4ddp)